# Removed domain in NGINX is redirecting to another site inside the server

Tags: nginx, ubuntu

I was asked to change a site from one digital ocean server to another, so I removed all configuration from the nginx server in the old digital ocean server but the domain is still working I have no idea why, I already removed the certbot certificates, why is this happening? The domain is redirecting to another site allowed in the same nginf configuration file it used be.

Commented lines belonged to the old domain.

```
server  {
    server_name chilecoaseguro.com www.chilecoaseguro.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/chilecoaseguro.com.access.log;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
            proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            proxy_read_timeout      120;
            proxy_redirect          http://127.0.0.1:8000 http://chilecoaseguro.com;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/chilecoaseguro.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/chilecoaseguro.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


} 

server  {
        server_name dev.chilecoaseguro.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/dev.chilecoaseguro.com.access.log;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
                proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8001;
                proxy_read_timeout      180;
                proxy_redirect          http://127.0.0.1:8001 http://dev.chilecoaseguro.com;
        }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.chilecoaseguro.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.chilecoaseguro.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

#server {
#   server_name inspecciones.naingenieria.cl;
#   access_log /var/log/nginx/inspecciones.naingenieria.cl.access.log;
#   client_max_body_size    150M;
#   location / {
#       proxy_set_header        Host $host;
 #               proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  #              proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   #             proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
    #            proxy_pass              http://0.0.0.0:9000;
     #           proxy_redirect          http://0.0.0.0:90000 http://inspecciones.naingenieria.cl;

#       proxy_connect_timeout   500s;
#               proxy_send_timeout      500s;
#               proxy_read_timeout      500s;
#               send_timeout            500s;
#       client_body_timeout     500s;
#   }

#   location /media {
#       autoindex off;
#       alias /root/Projects/projects/mapfre-inspecciones/mapfre-inspecciones/media/;
#       access_log off;
#   }


 #   listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  #  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/inspecciones.naingenieria.cl/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
   # ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/inspecciones.naingenieria.cl/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    #include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    #ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

#}


server  {
    if ($host = www.chilecoaseguro.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = chilecoaseguro.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name chilecoaseguro.com www.chilecoaseguro.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}


#server {
#    if ($host = inspecciones.naingenieria.cl) {
#        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
#    } # managed by Certbot


#   server_name inspecciones.naingenieria.cl;
#    listen 80;
#    return 404; # managed by Certbot


#}
 

server  {
    if ($host = dev.chilecoaseguro.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        server_name dev.chilecoaseguro.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a DNS issue. Did you also change the A record in DNS settings for that domain to point to the new server's IP. If you have then maybe changes are not propagated yet.

EDIT:
Where you change DNS records depends on where the domain's nameservers are (it's usually where the domain is registered). Chances are high that it's on digital ocean as well. You can see if that is the case by logging in to  digitalocean and checking under the **Network**  tab:
[like in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRJtA.png)
Then check for A record for that domain

EDIT2: you can also check for current settings by using the `dig` command from terminal, like this:

```
$ dig mydomain.com A
```

Comment: How can I check that? Maybe someone else did

Comment: I updated my answer, tell me if it works for you

Comment: Yes it did, you were right thank you!